# snprintf confusion 

Tags: c, string, printf

I am confused with snprintf function.
First of all I have not found the function snprintf in a turbo C version compiler under stdio.h 
Secondly in a GNU compiler snprintf is returning -1 when buffer size is smaller than formatted string ,though it should return the number of characters would have been printed if buffer size was sufficiently large. I have following source :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int numchar = snprintf(str,2,"ello jdj");
  printf("%d\n",numchar);
  return 0;
}
```

This code should output 8 according to as I know about snprintf so far. but it is returning -1 in my GNU compiler. What are the facts behind?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are using an old version of glibc. From the man page for `snprintf`:

> The  glibc  implementation of the functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() conforms to the C99 standard, that is, behaves as described above, since glibc version 2.1.  Until glibc 2.0.6 they would return -1 when the output was truncated.